# WPF: DataGrid: 1000 columns x 1200 rows

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am new in WPF and I need to make a datagrid of 1000 columns by 1200 rows.
Is it possible?
Any alternative other than the datagrid? I need to represent a table (Excel) of these features in my application. 
thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do it in advance?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used so many rows and columns for a wpf datagrid, but I guess doable although with performance and loading issues.

Assuming your number of columns as fixed, you can give it a try, provided:

1. you have UI virtualization enabled for datagrid for both rows as well as columns.

```
<wpftoolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" />
```

2. your datagrid's (if present in a control like stackpanel), has a fixed width and height (i.e. doesn't have them as Auto). Otherwise the virtualization would fail.

You may also want to think about data virtualization.

**Related**:

*WPF Datagrid and virtualization*: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/wpf/thread/9ea28468-5505-4e28-8220-e216b77ecf28

*Datagrid performance*: [WPF Datagrid Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697701/wpf-datagrid-performance)

*Data Virtualization and UI Virtualization*: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2009/09/06/ui-virtualization-vs-data-virtualization.aspx

PS: If you want excel like capabilities, you may also think about automating/embedding excel itself (would need excel to be installed on client machines).