# WPF DataGrid is very slow to render

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, render

I have tried using both a customized DataGrid as well as the stock one in WPF.  I have tried populating them manually as well as through bindings.  In both cases they are slow.

I have a scenerio where the user clicks on a button and a DataGrid appears with appropriate data.  Currently I am in proof of concept mode and just using sample data.  I have a DataSet with a table that has 10 rows in it.

If I don't attach any data to the DataGrid when I click the button the empty DataGrid displays pretty much instantly, a user cannot perceive a delay.  As soon as I add 10 rows of data, for 6 columns, the delay is about 2 seconds, very noticable to the user.

I even tried filling with empty data, just to get an empty grid to appear and it is equally as slow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    _dataGrid.Items.Add("");
```

I put a timer to count the ticks from when the button is clicked to when all of the code is executed to draw the DataGrid and it is around 20 milliseconds, so the code executes very fast, but on the screen is where the big lag is.  I tried a GridView and it renders much fast on the screen.

I have heard various reports of slow DataGrid drawing with complex scenarios and using 1000's of rows, but this is as simple as it gets, 6 columns by 10 rows filled with empty data.

For readonly display is GridView an equally viable option to the DataGrid?

---

Update

Here is the creation of my columns.

```
                DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                column.ColumnWidthChanged += new ColumnWidthChangedEventHandler(column_ColumnWidthChanged);

                column.Header = entity.GetPropertyValue("ColumnLabel");
                column.Binding = new Binding(entity.GetPropertyValue("Tag"));
                column.Width = new DataGridLength(entity.GetPropertyDouble("DisplaySize"));
                _dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```

This is a how I bind the DataSet with 10 rows in it.

```
                _dataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                _dataGrid.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];
```

Not sure what I can do differently.

Comment: I have tried the app on another system as well and it was slow as well.  The problem is that some view have multiple DataGrid's on them, so the delay just increases for each additional DataGrid.

Comment: i use the standard wpf datagrid with dynamic columns and more then 10000rows and have no problem with that. whats your itemssource? a datatable or somekind of collection? hopefully you did not add the items in a foreach like you post??

Comment: I tried the for loop as in the post just to see if it would make a difference, I wasn't sure if the binding was the problem.  In the real case I have a DataSet that I am binding.  I will update the post.

Comment: Very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697701/wpf-datagrid-performance/7413000#7413000

Comment: I am currently having the same issue, the code is executing pretty quickly, but the UI is updated in 6 minutes (my DataGrid has more than 60k items). None of the other comments seemed to help, did you manage to fix it somehow?

Answer (score 41):

Are you have:

- Enabled `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` for a Grid? if not - try to set.
- Set VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" for DataGrid
- Wrapped up a Grid by a StackPanel container? If yes - try to remove.
- Wrapped up a Grid by an external ScrollViewer control? If yes - try to remove.

One more point,
could you bind whole items collection at once instead of adding each item into the grid.Items collection?

Comment: Tried pasting my XAML but didn't come out well, I'll try and update my original question.  The DataGrid is contained within a DockPanel.  No to the ScrollViewer and I do not reference VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode.

Comment: Try to set VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode to Recycling, for instance: <Grid VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" ... />

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, but it doesn't appear to have helped.

Comment: Surely you tried to add this property to DataGrid control not a Grid? Also try to set VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="true" for DataGrid

Comment: Yes, I had tried it on a DataGrid, added IsVirtualizing as well and it actually seemed to slow it down.  I am really perplexed.  The code executes very fast, it is just the update that is slow.

Comment: Thanks man for the post, I didn`t think that inserting datagrid in stack panel can result in a rendering speed so much. In my case the difference in stack panel and outside was nearly 100 times.

Comment: Nothing of this works. DataGrid in WPF is far worse than the WinForms grid regarding performance, it's almost unusable.

Comment: @HrvojeBatrnek nothing of this worked for me as well, did you find any solution?

Comment: @RayaChorbadzhiyska yes. The problem is shadows effects, turn them off in the grid cells, in the grid containers, turn off all effects in the entire hierarchy and see what happens. My grid container had shadow effects. Shadow effects are very inefficient. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 35):

A general tip for `DataGrid` performance issues: I had a problem with the DataGrid in which it took literally seconds to refresh after a window resize, column sort, etc. and locked up the window UI while it was doing so (1000 rows, 5 columns).

It came down to an issue (bug?) with the WPF sizing calculations. I had it in a grid with the `RowDefinition` `Height="Auto"` which was causing the rendering system to try and recalculate the size of the DataGrid at runtime by measuring the size of each and every column and row, presumably by filling the whole grid (as I understand it). It is supposed to handle this intelligently somehow but in this case it was not.

A quick check to see if this is a related problem is to set the `Height` and `Width` properties of the DataGrid to a fixed size for the duration of the test, and try running again. If your performance is restored, a permanent fix may be among these options:

- Change the sizes of the containing elements to be relative (*) or
  fixed values
- Set `MaxHeight` and `MaxWidth` of the DataGrid to a fixed value larger
  than it could get in normal use
- Try another container type with different resizing strategy (`Grid`,
  `DockPanel`, etc)

Comment: I had the same problem with a DataGrid contained in a layout Grid's star-sized row. Setting MaxHeight as suggested works like a charm.

Answer (score 20):

[A blog](http://www.elegant-software.net/2014/05/performance-of-the-wpf-datagrid.html) I found on Google gave me a sort-of solution. As the author said, I disabled GroupStyle, and the rendering speed issue was solved. But I needed grouping. The author said

```
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping
```

is added to .NET 4.5. So I set it to true. Now rendering is quick with grouping. The problem is... scrolling is jerky. Not unacceptably jerky, but noticeably jerky. I had similar problem when I tried to create a TreeView with 2000+ nodes expanded. Without virtualisation, rendering was slow but scrolling was smooth. With virtualisation, rendering was quick but scrolling was jerky.

Why can't we have both...

Comment: This single line solved my exact problem - thank you very much! I was messing around with the asyn Task I'm using for loading the data when I finally realized that the rendering was the real problem. Added `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"` and the population of my DataGrid ist now down from around 10 seconds to less than a second.

Comment: This one also worked for me! Went down from 10-30 seconds to less than 1.

Comment: What is the solution when not using grouping?

Comment: This was the solution for me too. 
But "Why can't we have both..."? is a really good question.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I had a problem with DataGridCell ControlTemplate that slowed rendering way down.

Be aware that relative loading speeds for large dataset are very different for using **TextBlock** (that is not selectable text) or **TextBox** in ReadOnly mode:

**Loading time 59 seconds:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DataGridCellTextStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/> 
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Loading time 21 seconds:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DataGridCellTextStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                     <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Loading time 16 seconds:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="DataGridCellTextStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 7):

Well a little bit adding more (i know its very old topic, but still it helps someone)...

I tried

```
EnableColumnVirtualization="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
EnableRowVirtualization="True"
```

for DataGrid(`AutoGenerateColumns="True"`) binding to DataTable.DefaultView() and No effect on speed, it was still horrible for Speed as well as for navigation between rows. Than, I came up with solution to set Fixed Height and Width of DataGrid. Additionally I also set

```
RowHeight="23" 
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
```

This makes my page fill very fast... Instead of 2 min, now it takes hardly 10-12 seconds.

Hope it helps someone.

Note: I am using .Net 4.5

Answer (score 5):

For me it was:

```
<Setter Property='ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll' Value='False' />
```

I removed this from the style and the rendering became fast.

Comment: To clarify, set ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to `true` as a value of `false` will disable virtualization.

Comment: With CanContentScroll on false I had 20s load time... on true, load time is instant. But the smooth scrolling is gone.

Comment: Use this `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="pixel"` for smooth scrolling

Answer (score 5):

I was having big issues with 1000 rows, 5 columns where the render time was taking 7-10 seconds, but the solution found at https://www.elegant-software.net/2014/05/performance-of-the-wpf-datagrid.html made the grid load instantly!

```
<DataGrid
   EnableRowVirtualization="True"
   EnableColumnVirtualization="True">
```

Comment: As a quick update on this - In my scenario, I had a checkbox at the end of each row for users to select which rows they needed and once complete, they would submit the selected, but I found when row virtualisation was enabled, due to its nature of only rendering what's on screen, it didn't count the selected rows that were not visible on screen which led to a couple of issues. 
To combat this, I added/removed the selected IDs to a hashset variable whenever the row was selected, and tracked them this way

Answer (score 2):

I have a Surface Pro 3 on which my datagrid, with about 200 rows and 10 columns, was really slow at scrolling, jerky and hesitant.

I thought it was the network, but it was in fact the graphics card not being able to keep up with - wait for it - a drop shadow effect on the datagrid itself, even though the background of the control was set to a solid colour.

I commented out the effect and it was 4-5 times faster.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with bound Data grid, and I notice that in first load it is fast but on secand and next it is slow. So when I add in code

`DataGrid.ItemsSource = Nothing` and then `TableAdapter.Fill(Mydataset.MyStoredProcedure,....) DataGrid.ItemsSource=Mydataset.MyStoredProcedure` it became very FAST

Comment: sorry, May I know more detail?

Comment: Need more details as you can tell there seem to be a lot of performance issues with the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` set on my DataGrid. This disables virtualization all together for the DataGrid. More info about this can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724695/4383302

Answer (score 0):

If you have a row definition like below:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition x:Name="topRow" Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition x:Name="mainRow" Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition x:Name="dataGridRow" Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

You must be careful! If your DataGrid is in one of these rows, then it will be resized for every row over and over again. If you have 1000 rows, then it will be resized 1000 times!

Now assume that your DataGrid is in the 3rd `RowDefinition` then I suggest you change the code this way:

```
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="topRow" Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="mainRow" Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="dataGridRow" Height="400"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Of course, you can change `"400"` how you wish.