# WPF populating DataGrid with large table blocking my UI thread

Tags: wpf, user-interface, async-await, freeze, blocking

I've spent some time researching and observing the best practices to avoid blocking the UI thread when attempting to process data on the UI thread.  Specifically, I utilize the async/await where I can.  However, when populating a DataGrid via Binding, I noticed my UI freezes up after command processing is completed and processing is passed back to the UI.

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EndpointModel.DataView}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True">            
</DataGrid>
```

DataModel command execution:

```
public async void CommandExecute()
{
    ...

    JsonData = await accessor.GetDataAsync(new Endpoint.Params().Universe(universe)
                                                                .WithStart(start)
                                                                .WithEnd(end));

    // Creates a very large DataTable within my display (30 x 350)
    var grid = EndpointModel.CreateDataGrid(JsonData);      
    EndpointModel.DataView = grid.AsDataView();
}
```

I've stepped through the code to observe processing times, placed debugger messages and processing seems normal.  The await statement takes about 1.5 seconds and the grid processing at the end is a few ms.  Yet, when I return from the 'CommandExecute()', it takes about 3-5 seconds before the UI is responsive.  The data populates fine - it just takes forever.  I don't know if this is expected or whether I have control over this.

thanks.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue, but in my case it takes 6 minutes to populate the data!! How did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

WPF DataGrid is known for its performance issues. You can try to go through answers from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680879/wpf-datagrid-is-very-slow-to-render). 
Basically, most recommended option is: using Grid. Especially if rows counts thousands.
Or, if you want to keep datagrid, there are such ways to decrease loading time as

```
EnableColumnVirtualization = true
EnableRowVirtualization = true
```

Also set fixed width and/or height, datagrid may try to recalculate required width and height every time there is data updated. Id check other threads to optimize your datagrid to your needs.